# How to resize a div with handles using javascript or CSS(without using resize property) or with other libraries?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is that the `resize` property in CSS has only one handle at the right bottom corner and it resizes on both sides at the same time and doesn't work like a normal resize. Is there any library or any easy way to resize a div with at least 4 handles?

```css
#resizeit{
  background-color: green;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  
  padding:auto;
  margin:auto;


}
#buttonclass {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="resizeit"><button id='buttonclass' >Hello</button> </div>
```

Comment: https://htmldom.dev/make-a-resizable-element/

Comment: Hi thanks for replying,i also need handles to resize the div